# Netbeans won't open port 9000 for XDebug

Tags: netbeans, xdebug

I'm working on Windows 7, NetBeans 8, jdk-1.8.0-b132 and I'm having trouble with NetBeans and XDebug. Basically NetBeans at random times fails to open and listen on port 9000 after launching debugger through Debug -> Debug project (my_project). Before and after launching debugger (on machine where NetBeans is running)

```
netstat -an|grep 9000
```

shows nothing. As I said it happens randomly (usually NetBeans succeeds to open the port after I restart it). In NetBeans debugger port is set to 9000, and nothing is listening on port 9000. Windows firewall is off.

Is there some log that I can inspect to find out what's going on?

Also, when NetBeans eventually manages to open the port it sometimes fails to close it after debugging session is finished (Debug -> Finish debugging session) - which I check using netstat/TCPView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is already somewhat older. If others are looking for the documentation for netbeans DBGP/xdebug logging:

> Running NetBeans with logging turned on. You can do this by:
>   either adding the text:
>
> `-J-Dorg.netbeans.modules.php.dbgp.level=400`
>
> to your 
>   $NB_BIN/etc/netbeans.conf, property netbeans_default_options
>   or
>   running NetBeans directly with those parameters, like:
>
> `$NB_BIN/bin/netbeans -J-Dorg.netbeans.modules.php.dbgp.level=400`
>
> the content of IDE log file Menu -> View -> IDE Log File (or directly 
>   $YOUR_NB_USER_DIR/var/log/messages.log) the content of the Output Window

See http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug and https://xdebug.org/docs-dbgp.php